# Eclipse Java Debugger just stepping after first resume

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Using eclipse juno 4.4.1 with JDK8
Simple java application/junit (does not matter) debugging working properly just after first resume:

1. setting breakpoints
2. debug
3. debugger holds on *first breakpoint*

   - resume, suspend, terminate enabled
   - *step* into, step over, step return *disabled* (grey)
   - variables not listed
4. after resume the debugger *works fine on next breakpoint* (stepping & vars)

Already tried new projects, new workspace, export/import several settings.
->
the problem dissappeared on a new fresh workspace
might be a configuration/plug-in issue but could not isolate it
when I thought I got it the issue appeared again (on restart of eclipse)

Any ideas?

== as requested, but the problem seems to rely on eclipse, not on code or sdk

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(""); // BP1, debugger holds but no stepping, vars
    System.out.println(""); // BP2, debugger holds after resume, stepping available, vars shown
}
```

**UPDATE**
It's the thread focus (context switch) in the Debug view. When I manually select the main thread, I can (trivially) control and see it again.

**QUESTION**
How do I autoselect the main thread/context of first break point?
currently, the first line is selected ("App (4) [Java Application]") after starting debug.

Stack dump:

```
App (4) [Java Application]  
    com.test.App at localhost:52658 
        Thread Group [system]   
            Daemon System Thread [Reference Handler] (Running)  
            Daemon System Thread [Finalizer] (Running)  
            Daemon System Thread [Signal Dispatcher] (Running)  
            Daemon System Thread [Attach Listener] (Running)    
            Thread Group [main] 
                Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 6 in com.test.App))    
                    com.test.App.main(java.lang.String[]) line: 6   
    C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe (10.11.2014 17:38:26)
```

Comment: Do you have general breakpoints on certain exceptions? e.g. catch all NullPointerExceptions? And are you using special frameworks or plugins? So you are using a blank eclipse without plugins, and you are not using Spring, Maven etc?

Comment: just simple:
public static void main(String[] args){
<break> System.out.println("test");
...

Comment: Could you post the code and tell us with some comments for which line you added the breakpoint at? Because then we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Using JavaEE, additional plug-in: runJettyRun
using plain java project: no server, no maven; same issue with JUnit

Comment: Can you check what happens if you suspend instead of resume?

Comment: suspend remains the options to resume or to stop, but no stepping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear:
Make sure that Window/Show View/Debug>(arrow down button)/Java/Show Thread Groups is UNSELECTED